# Node analysis problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

trying to solve using Node method I have stuck.

[image]

R1=6800    R2=5600 V1=5 V2=-7.2

I am stuck, is it:

((e-5)/6800 + (e- (-7.2))/5600=0

((e-5)/6800 + (e+7.2))/5600=0

or

((e-5)/6800 + (e-7.2))/5600=0

Answer (score 1):

The equation for node e is simple. Use KCL to sum the currents leaving (or equivalently entering) the node: In your case we write the equation for node e as follows:

{e-(V1)}/R1 + {e-(-V2)}/R2=0.

Now solve for e.